# How do I interpret the information regarding the Vivobook S400CA battery life?

Tags: hardware-rec, battery-life

I'm interested in an ultrabook, but I cannot understand it's battery life's spec.

The model's [website](http://www.asus.com.au/Notebooks/Superior_Mobility/S400CA/#specifications) indicates that it has

> 44 Whrs Polymer Battery

How does this information translates into the number of hours in a day?
Is this information sufficient to calculate? If not, are there any ways to approximate and what kind of additional information is needed? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the reviews I read on that specific model the majority of them said it had above average battery life. Its difficult to say the exact amount of hours it will last because that could vary based on amount of use, power settings etc.